# IONIC - CAPACITOR - VUE.JS - App display in background when I scroll down the menu phone

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, ionic3, capacitor

I'm new to app developing, and I'm trying to develop a music app with Ionic, Capacitor and Vue.js.
Does anyone know if there is a way to place your app in the background and HOW TO DISPLAY IT when I slide down the phone menu from the top or when the phone is locked? (as Spotify for example).
Or this image as an example https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-eb92eaabdcd3a7633bba9c1703cbf88a-pjlq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BZUe.jpg)

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugins that may be of use.  The [Capacitor Background Task](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/background-task) plugin can run tasks for a limited amount of time.  However, it's not recommended.  Capacitor wasn't designed for hyper-immersive apps like music players.  This third-party [Music Controls](https://github.com/ingageco/capacitor-music-controls-plugin) plugin may also be helpful.

> Note: both of these plugins were designed for Capacitor 2.  It's often possible to get them working in v3, but may take some fiddling or forking.